# Optocoupler Rf calculation

Tags: opto-isolator

I am using FODM124 optocoupler. And I want to work in Saturation mode.
How to choose VF,IF,CTR and how to calculate Rf??
Bcoz i am seeing different IF's in the datasheet for different Vce's?
What exactly Vce relates with??

Please clarify.

With Regards,
Chaithra[image: Optocoupler characteristics.]

[image: Opto Ckt]

Comment: You will never get saturation if you connect the collector directly to VCC. And what does "48V,110V" mean?

Comment: Hello,

Vcc is connected directly to the Vcc. Rc is connected between Vcc and Collector of phototransistor.
48V and 110V are my digital inputs.
Digital world I have to isolate from the circuit thats why I am using optocoupler.
The circuit should design with less input current say 5mA or less. For this condition how to choose CTR, VF,??


With Regards,
Chaithra Y.S

Comment: There is no Rc in the circuit you've shown. And it is not possible to have 48V and 110V on the same line.

Answer (score 2):

Do NOT connect collector to VCC and emitter to the ground directly because your optocoupler will be broken if the transistor ON.

Use this circuit for using optocoupler

[image: optocoupler]

With this circuit, we can calculate R1.

R1 = (Vin - Vf)/If

Based on [this](http://www.promelec.ru/pdf/FODM2705.pdf) datasheet, dioda forward voltage maximum Vf = 1.3v. If = 1 mA for saturation. We can use 5 mA (maximum 50 mA) to make sure the transistor saturated.

So,

For Vin= 48 volt, R1 = (48-1.3)/0.005 = 9340 Ohm

For Vin= 110 volt, R1 = (110-1.3)/0.005 = 21740 Ohm

Using resistor 10k (0.5 Watt) for 48 volt and 20k (1 Watt) for 110 volt is fine.